# Android Intent.EXTRA_STREAM Question

Tags: android, email, sms, android-intent

-

The description of the [`Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) says:

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent,
>   **used with ACTION_SEND** to supply the data being sent.

-

***My question is:*** Can I use the **`EXTRA_STREAM`** with the [**`ACTION_SENDTO`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO) to send attachment with SMS ?

If I can't, is there a way to send attachment with SMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is usually used for email but you may use it for SMS, although not all file types are supported.

I'm pretty sure you will run into trouble when trying to attach streams that aren't images. There are a lot of complaints about this and I personally have yet to accomplish this, (in an SMS)

Comment: What are the supported ones?. I tried it with Audio/basic but nothing seems to be attached !